# Substring keeps giving StringIndexOutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, android, string, substring

So I'm using a list of strings that I have inputted, so all the strings are there, but when I try to use substring on them, it keeps giving me the StringIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Here's the code:

```
List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
            String entered = text.getText().toString().trim();
            String[] query = entered.split(" ");
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeString;i++)
            {
                temp = a[i].indexOf(" ");
                if (query[0].toLowerCase().matches(a[i].toLowerCase().substring(0,temp)))
                    li.add(a[i]);
            }
```

---

Okay so now my arrayadapter is giving me a null pointer
adb won't tell me what besides its nullpointer 
Full code:

```
public void onClick (View v)
        {
            List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
            String entered = text.getText().toString().trim();
            String[] query = entered.split(" ");
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeString;i++)
            {
                if ( a[i].indexOf ( " " ) != -1 )
                    {
                        temp = a[i].indexOf(" ");
                        a[i].substring(0,temp);
                    }
                if (query[0].toLowerCase().equals(a[i].toLowerCase()))
                    li.add(a[i]);                   
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.search_results);
            final ListView list= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.search_list);
            String[] results = new String[sizeString];
            for(int i = 0; i<li.size();i++)
                results[i]=li.get(i);
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Browse.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,results));
        }
```

Comment: I think we discussed this in another thread, please add System.out right before if(query[0]...) statment for a[i] and temp values. This will give you clue why it is throwing error. As we discussed, if a[i] lenght is less than substring(0,temp) length, it will throw StringIndexOutofBound Exception

Comment: Please avoid repeated postings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no space, then temp will be -1, you should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a check for a return of -1 from  indexOf()

Answer (score 0):

put this condition in your code `if ( a[i].indexOf ( " " ) != -1 )` before this line `temp = a[i].indexOf(" ");`